# Quiz generated from JavaScript not loading until refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Weird issue. Made a trivia game using Javascript, and it loads --- but only after a refresh. Though I call the Javascript at (ready), it initially only loads a radio button with no text. But with a refresh, everything is fixed. Any idea what I should do to get it to load correctly when the page opens?

In my HTML file, I am loading a five question quiz:

```
<!-- First Trivia Example --> 

<div id="content">
       <h3 id="question"></h3>
       <div id="choices"></div>
       <p><button id="submit"></button></p>
       <p id="score"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Those elements come from the .js file in my App > Assets > Javascripts directory of my RoR file, and I am calling it at ready.

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 

      var quiz = [{
      "question": "What is the full form of IP?",
      "choices": ["Internet Provider", "Internet Port", "Internet Protocol"],
      "correct": "Internet Protocol"
    }, {
      "question": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
      "choices": ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak"],
      "correct": "Bill Gates"
    }, {
      "question": "1 byte = ?",
      "choices": ["8 bits", "64 bits", "1024 bits"],
      "correct": "8 bits"
    }, {
      "question": "The C programming language was developed by?",
      "choices": ["Brendan Eich", "Dennis Ritchie", "Guido van Rossum"],
      "correct": "Dennis Ritchie"
    }, {
      "question": "What does CC mean in emails?",
      "choices": ["Carbon Copy", "Creative Commons", "other"],
      "correct": "Carbon Copy"
    }];


    // define elements
    var content = $("content"),
      questionContainer = $("question"),
      choicesContainer = $("choices"),
      scoreContainer = $("score"),
      submitBtn = $("submit");

    // init vars
    var currentQuestion = 0,
      score = 0,
      askingQuestion = true;

    function $(id) { // shortcut for document.getElementById
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function askQuestion() {
      var choices = quiz[currentQuestion].choices,
        choicesHtml = "";

      // loop through choices, and create radio buttons
      for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        choicesHtml += "<input type='radio' name='quiz" + currentQuestion +
          "' id='choice" + (i + 1) +
          "' value='" + choices[i] + "'>" +
          " <label for='choice" + (i + 1) + "'>" + choices[i] + "</label><br>";
      }

      // load the question
      questionContainer.textContent = "Q" + (currentQuestion + 1) + ". " +
        quiz[currentQuestion].question;

      // load the choices
      choicesContainer.innerHTML = choicesHtml;

      // setup for the first time
      if (currentQuestion === 0) {
        scoreContainer.textContent = "Score: 0 right answers out of " +
          quiz.length + " possible.";
        submitBtn.textContent = "Submit Answer";
      }
    }

    function checkAnswer() {
      // are we asking a question, or proceeding to next question?
      if (askingQuestion) {
        submitBtn.textContent = "Next Question";
        askingQuestion = false;

        // determine which radio button they clicked
        var userpick,
          correctIndex,
          radios = document.getElementsByName("quiz" + currentQuestion);
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
          if (radios[i].checked) { // if this radio button is checked
            userpick = radios[i].value;
          }

          // get index of correct answer
          if (radios[i].value == quiz[currentQuestion].correct) {
            correctIndex = i;
          }
        }

        // setup if they got it right, or wrong
        var labelStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("label")[correctIndex].style;
        labelStyle.fontWeight = "bold";
        if (userpick == quiz[currentQuestion].correct) {
          score++;
          labelStyle.color = "green";
        } else {
          labelStyle.color = "red";
        }

        scoreContainer.textContent = "Score: " + score + " right answers out of " +
          quiz.length + " possible.";
      } else { // move to next question
        // setting up so user can ask a question
        askingQuestion = true;
        // change button text back to "Submit Answer"
        submitBtn.textContent = "Submit Answer";
        // if we're not on last question, increase question number
        if (currentQuestion < quiz.length - 1) {
          currentQuestion++;
          askQuestion();
        } else {
          showFinalResults();
        }
      }
    }

    function showFinalResults() {
      content.innerHTML = "<h2>You've completed the quiz!</h2>" +
        "<h2>Below are your results:</h2>" +
        "<h2>" + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " questions, " +
        Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + "%<h2>";
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", askQuestion, false);
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer, false);

    });
```

Comment: I'd probably blame turbolinks :)

Comment: Yikes. So I am calling the application.js using <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>, and I was thinking the turbolinks gem should load correctly, no?

Comment: @darkginger : Have you check my answer??

Answer (score 0):

It works fine... Confirm that you have installed `gem 'jquery-rails'`, Also check your `application.js` file under `app/assets/javascript/application.js`  Have you inserted Jquery..

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

check in your `app/views/layout/application.html.erb` there should be

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

### [Your Code's Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/gm2bvvwy/)

---

**Issue** in your current `Jquery` Code:

- Your Code Start Quiz from Question 2nd (`Q2`)

Because You have initialized `var currentQuestion`
 as `0` and in your `// load the question`
 portion  defined

```
questionContainer.textContent = "Q" + (currentQuestion + 1) + ". " + quiz[currentQuestion].question;
```

(currentQuestion + 1) will became (0+1) as it starts index from `1` and in array index starts from `0` That's why your first question is not appear..

**Solution:** initialized `var currentQuestion` as `-1` instead of `0`

### [Corrected Code's Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gm2bvvwy/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in this case. When I run it exclusively on HTML with an external .js file, you are totally right that it works. Within this RoR structure, something does seem to be interfering with the loading. Per the previous poster, I am investigating whether the turbolinks gem is to blame, which I think is a possibility. Will weigh in once I figure it out.

Comment: Wait. Actually, I may have been wrong. Click on your Corrected Demo link to jsfiddle again. Do you see in the run window where there is just a checkbox rather than the first question when we change the currentQuestion var to -1? That is the same issue I am seeing in the final product as far as the first question not loading on document ready. I tried this in Chrome and Firefox, and I am seeing the same thing. Do you see that as well?

Comment: @darkginger : Please check that you have not given same id to multiple elements.. It may also let you u not work..